# Android Dragon board 820 - Add System Service

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am trying to add an Android System Service in 6.0.1.

I implemented an example for adding Android System Service.
The Android System builds everything fine without any errors.

But I always get an exception in run-time when trying to register the JNI class method.

In the following part:

```
int register_android_server_xxxService(JNIEnv *env)
{
    return jniRegisterNativeMethods(env, "com/android/server/xxxService",
    method_table, NELEM(method_table));
};
```

The system can't find the class.

The is the device boot log:

> art     : Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class
>   java.lang.Class
>
> 01-01 00:58:16.319  2806  2806 I art     : Rejecting re-init on
>   previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>
> 01-01 00:58:16.334  2806  2806 W SystemServer: System clock is before
>   1970; setting to 1970.
>
> 01-01 00:58:16.335  2806  2806 I SystemServer: Entered the Android
>   system server!
>
> 01-01 00:58:16.355  2806  2806 I art     : Rejecting re-init on
>   previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>
> 01-01 00:58:16.356  2806  2806 F art     :
>   art/runtime/jni_internal.cc:497] JNI FatalError called: Native
>   registration unable to find class 'com/android/server/xxxService';
>   aborting...

I tried a few examples but always the same result, I'm compiling Android 6.0.1 with msm8996.

Has it happened before to anyone?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and it was due to not putting the java file on proper location and defining the path properly. You can try this.

```
int register_android_server_xxxService(JNIEnv *env)
{
return jniRegisterNativeMethods(env, "com/android/server/xxx/xxxService",
method_table, NELEM(method_table));
};
```

And put the xxxService.java file in frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/xxx/xxxService.java

Comment: I already saw this problem. its not the issue. there is something strange about the development board.  tried the following: keep devices in boot loop (cuz of no class def), and perform adb sync on frameworks/base/ and walla! device loaded ok and service if started! BUTTTTT after boot, everything fails again. There is some weird thing that the boot process does that i dont understand.